# Bigger text icons in Action bar

Tags: android, android-xml

I have this design to achieve:
[image]

but the result I got is this:
[image]

As you can see I am asked to create the submit button much larger that it actually is, I've tried setting it as an image with no luck, also I've tried entering it as normal text and manipulate the theme but that didn't work either, I'm using the latest and greatest API 21 .. Lollipop.

here's the code to the item in my menu:

```
<item
    android1:title="submit"
    android1:id="@+id/userLoginSubmitActionBar"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
```

Comment: Do oyu use custom Toolbar or an Action Bar? If Action Bar follow this guide https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomText apart from color you can customize title size, weight etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `android:actionLayout` attribute of the `<item>` tag? It will let you set a custom layout to be displayed.  You could use a `TextView` and set the text size appropriately :)

As for the arrows, if I am not wrong, `<` means up navigation while `<-` means presence of a navigation drawer, right?

Comment: forget about the arrows, the designs came old and we are using android 5.0 material designs so they're good, as to the action bar item, I will try this immediately thanks :D

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work, I've added a new layout xml file with a big text view and set it to the item as u've said with no luck :-(

Comment: This is interesting. I havent tried API Lv 21 as yet :/

Answer (score 0):

This is really a hack I suppose but what the hell, here's my solution to my own contribution, 
I've set
  `<item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">`

to my own custom theme parenting from

```
 <style name="myStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
```

and the damn thing worked like magic ! haha... thank u guys, really, no need for the drum rolls in the background :D